# Adding team to our IBM Quantum Experience account

Tags: ibm-q-experience

I have an account and API token on IBM Quantum Experience (https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/)

I would like to add team members to the account, so that everyone can use it without sharing login credentials.

It doesn't look like IBMQ is integrated with IBM Cloud IAM (we have an IBM Cloud account). I asked their support team and they suggested I post the question here.

Does anyone know if it is possible to add team members to an IBMQ account?

Thank you!

Comment: I don’t think this feature is currently supported. What do you want to achieve by sharing the account?

Comment: With the latest Qiskit Experiments released this week though, you can share experiments with others: https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/lab/docs/iql/manage/experiments/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Junye Huang! - We were trying to share an account so different people in our team could monitor jobs without having to share a single set of login credentials.

Comment: For that purpose you can either share the login credentials of the IBM Quantum account with your team members (which is obvious) or share your account token with the team and each person can use job monitor in Qiskit to monitor your jobs using locks Python environment such as Jupyter notebook. Watch this short tutorial video for more details: https://youtu.be/ozy0b7eE-lo